# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type: arrow function in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package

now I'm creating a npm package
and I have a trouble with code below:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     }
| 
|     holenNummerInSchnur = Schnur => {
|       if (this.beurteilenHatNummer(Schnur)) {
|         return Schnur.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)[0]
```

this arrow function is inside a react component
and I think I'm sure the core problem is arrow function:
because when I change an arrow function to es5 function, then error will transfer to next arrow function

so I want to know 2 point:

1. how to solve this problem ?
2. why will this problem happen ? because I have created another simple package and content is very easy:

```
exports.printMsg = () => { console.log('hey u')}
```

it's okay! it works! and it's still an arrow function!
what is the difference between these two arrow function?
(the only difference I can find is that the trouble one is in react Component and thie other is not, but I'm not sure whether this is the key to this problem)

Comment: Do you have Babel?

Comment: except Babel, should I use webpack??                        
if I just wanna solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides in webpack/babel and not in your code.
Basically with react, when a build comes, you are **transpilling ES6/ES7 code to ES5**, to do this, babel have to know what are the rules for correct transpilling:

Ref: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions

Nowadays most of the browsers understand es6, this is because your second snippet works.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, class properties, which are the arrow function you declared, are not part of the ES6 specification.

To use it, in your `.babelrc` file, you append `"transform-class-properties"` to the `plugins` array, like so:

```
{
  "presets": [ ... ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
  ]
}
```

Don't forget to install `npm i babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --save-dev`.

Comment: except .babelrc 
should I set up the webpack file or I don't need that if I just want to solve this problem ?